# Anchor tag Not working at all

Tags: apostrophe, apostrophe-cms

{{ apos.singleton(data.page, 'BLPHeroDisclaimerOptionONe', 'apostrophe-rich-text', { addLabel:"Hero Disclaimer",
                    toolbar:
                    ['Bold','Superscript','Italic',
                    'Subscript', 'Superscript', 'Link', 'Unlink', 'Anchor'],
                    styles: [
                    { name: 'paragraph', element: 'p' }
                    ]
                    }) }}

in the obove code we had Anchor tag and i had enter the id of a div to which i want page to scroll to but its not working at all , 
Any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you you confirm in your rendered HTML is all looking correct?

You are getting both a `<a href="#someId">Jump Link</a>` and a `<div id="someId">Important Content</div>`